# Composer create local package

Tags: php, json, composer-php

In my project inside the `vendor` directory I created a new directory named `Hello` and created a new class `HelloWorld.php` with the namespace `Hello\Test`. Then in the root of `Hello` I created a `composer.json` with default meta data (`author`, `license`, `desc`, `required`), and added autoload PSR-4 `Hello\\Test\\`.

So what do I need to do next to autoload my package. I looked at some Symfony components and their `composer.json` package and configuration is the same.

Is it possible to autoload my local package from `vendor` like this?

**Dir structure:**

```
|-my_project
|-composer.json
|---vendor
|-------composer
|-------autoload.php
|-------Hello
|-----------composer.json
|-----------HelloWorld.php
```

./vendor/Hello/composer.json

```
{
  "name": "Zend/Hello",
  "description": "My test package",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Zend Zend",
      "email": "test@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Hello\\Test\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

My HelloWorld.php class has `namespace Hello\Test;`
Inside `index.php` i do `include 'vendor/autoload.php`
And root composer.json

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "": "src/",
      "Hello\\Test\\": "./vendor/Hello"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "Hello/Test": "*"
  }

}
```

`composer update`

Comment: Have you tried running `composer update` ?

Comment: Yup but nothing is happening. When i try to create instance in `index.php` where i `include` autload i get error class not found.

Comment: Ok then. Could you paste the `psr-4` declaration in your composer.json? and your Hello directory structure?

Comment: check now new update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay! Sorry for the late reply.
You only need one composer.json to make this work. The one in your main project directory.

Try using this:

```
{
   "name": "Zend/Hello",
   "description": "My test package",
   "license": "MIT",
   "authors": [
      {
          "name": "Zend Zend",
          "email": "test@example.com"
      }
   ],
   "autoload": {
       "psr-4": {
           "Hello\\Test\\": "vendor/Hello"
       }
   }
}
```

And your HelloWorld.php file should be like:

```
<?php

namespace Hello\Test;

class HelloWorld {

    // your methods goes here
}
```

Run a composer self update to get the latest composer the run `composer update` and it should now be added to your vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php file